# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS does not display/list my Samsung 950 Pro NVMe 256GB SSD under "Devices"

Tags: drivers, ssd, samsung, devices, nvme

**Does anyone know why I am unable to see the Samsung 950 NVMe 25GB SSD listed under "Devices" while logged into ubuntu 14.04 LTS???**

I was able to install ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my new Samsung 950 Pro NVMe 256GB SSD first by unplugging my only other HDD; then by booting with a Windows 7 Pro ISO disk inserted into my CD drive.

However, when I'm logged into ubuntu I do not see the Samsung 950 NVMe 25GB SSD listed under "Devices". I only see my CD drive and my SATA drive that I have since reconnected. I don't see the Samsung 950 Pro SSD. Why?

Comment: Reading this question, it's not clear where the "Devices" you're looking at is. Is it the output of a command, or an entry in a settings window somewhere? Perhaps you mean the Devices listing under the "Disk" utility?